# Unable to select device for WatchOS app in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, watchos

[image: 1]

This is shown in Xcode when trying to select device to build the WatchOS app.
My Apple Watch series 5 is paired with my iPhoneXs.
My iPhone uses the latest iOS version `16.0.2` and my Watch uses the latest WatchOS version `9.0.2`
My Xcode version is also the latest one - `14.0`

When clicking this `GET` button, it tries to download the watchOS 9.0 Simulator, and it succeeds, but it fails when trying to install it, see images below:

[image: 2]

and then:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by removing installed watchOS 9.0 platform in Xcode, and installing it again by pressing `GET` button as posted in question.

Steps to uninstall:

- Go to `Xcode > Preferences > Platforms`
- Select watchOS as it is shown on the image below
- Click `-` button
- Confirm by pressing `Delete` on pop-up
- Delete Derived data (not sure if this is needed)
- Relaunch Xcode and tap `GET` button again

Thats it!

[image: 1]

Installation successful:

[image: 2]